# Finding the most frequent value in a GeoTIFF

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff

I am working on a project where I am using GeoTIFFs that were generated with software that has a bug.  The bug in the software is assigning the "nodata" value with a random selection.

For example, [this is a link to one of these GeoTIFFs on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10IDo_iX5RzEd1BLuAk9tKdynZXsBUO3o/view?usp=sharing).

In the example above, the nodata value is -15. It could also be something like 5, -11, 0 or anything. I have no control over the creation of the GeoTIFFs, so I need to somehow figure out what the most common value in the image is.

Because of the nature of the data, I know that the most common value is always going to be the nodata value. Is there anything in GDAL (or any other tool or method) where I can find the most common value in the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use QGIS with gdal and numpy libraries:

```
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal
ds = gdal.Open(r"/home/bera/GIS/Segmentering_test/B02_clipped.tif")
band1 = np.array(ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())

counts = np.bincount(np.reshape(band1, band1.size)) #bincount wants a 1D array, so I reshape it from 2D to 1D
print(np.argmax(counts))
```

218 is most common:
[image]